# insert iframe on chrome.tabs.onupdated listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been trying to add the iframe in the google page when the tab is being updated. The iframe shows the updated url and the title. Programmtically it shows that that the iframe has been inserted but i cannot see the iframe on the page.
Following is the code in my content script:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) { //onUpdated should fire when the selected tab is changed or a link is clicked 
  if (changeInfo.status == "complete") {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
        if (tab.url.indexOf(".google.") != -1) {
            url = getRetailer(tab.url);
            title = tab.title;
            title = tab.title.replace(" - Google Search", "");
            createiframe(url, title);
        }

    });
  }
});

function createIframe(url, PN, uid) {
   var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   iframe.src = "url:" + url + 'title:" + PN ;
   iframe.setAttribute("id", "cr_Iframe");
   iframe.setAttribute("style", "position: fixed; z-index: 100001; left: 0pt; right: 0pt; top: 0pt; width: 100%; height: 42px; display: block;");
   iframe.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
   iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
   iframe.setAttribute("name", "cr_Iframe");
   document.body.insertBefore(iframe, document.body.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: Have you added the required permission in the manifest.json for the url you are using? Are there any errors in the console.

Comment: what permission will i have to add in manifest.json? i have already added permission as "permissions": [ "http://*/", "https://*/", "tabs"]  is there anything required more.

Comment: No thats about it.Are there any errors on the console?

Answer (score 2):

You're creating the iframe inside your extension background page or pop-up page or whatever. You'll need to pass the whole code to a content script, either via `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` or directly via manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["*://*.google.*"],
     "js": ["body_of_createIframe_function.js"]
   }
 ],
```

Comment: @AshwinMendon you're welcome. you should also at least accept & upvote this answer if you find it useful. It'll help you get more help in the future